# How to not change value of object when function call?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a object has property called `CountItem` as:

```
Object.CountItem
```

The value it has `0`.

When I call the following function:

```
DoSomeThing(Object, out Count);
 // -> public object DoSomeThing(ObjectClass Object, out int Count)
```

In function, I change `Object.CountItem = 2;`

After the function is run, value of my object changed, and now  `Object.CountItem` is `2`

I don't understand why my variable not out var has been changed value?

Comment: please give some example of code and output, it is unclear

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Answer (score 2):

Your object is of reference type, changing it inside any method will change the object.  Out applies to value type objects(like int, bool,etc)

Comment: oh, i set out for variable int named is Count. this is run. But i don't use out for variable why property has been change. you can editing for me?

Comment: how i can do function not change value my object

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to the out parameter before you leave the scope of the method